# how to Configure href url for flutter web in index.html

Tags: flutter, dart, href, flutter-web

i am trying to run my existing flutter application on web, after adding the support for web and adding firebase javascript code to my index.html, when i run the application on  a browser i get this error

> If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change
> the href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.
> The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order
> for it to work correctly. Fore more details: *
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base -->

i have tried looking for solution online but i could not find any, i have tried following this https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation/url-strategies but its not working for me please any help will be appreciated thanks
Bellow is my index.html file

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    
    
        If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
        href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.
    
        The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
        it to work correctly.
    
        Fore more details:
        * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
      -->
      <base href="/">
    
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
      <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">
    
      <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="st_anthony_app">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">
    
      <!-- Favicon -->
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
    
      <title>st_anthony_app</title>
      <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.3/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script>
    
      var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "xxxxxenter`enter code here`",
        authDomain: "xxxxx",
        databaseURL: "xxxxx",
        projectId: "xxxxx",
        storageBucket: "xxxxx",
        messagingSenderId: "xxxxx",
        appId: "xxxxx",
        measurementId: "xxxxx"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


  </script>
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->

  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```